# SwiftでBundleにAudioファイルを保存したい

Tags: swift

Bundleに録音データを保存したいのですがうまくいきません。

Documentフォルダに録音したファイルを保存するコードは問題なく動いており、以下のようになっています。

```
var audioFilename: URL!

//Audio録音周りの関数
func startRecording() {
    audioFilename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recordedAudio.wav")

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()

    } catch {
        finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}

func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    audioRecorder = nil
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
```

データをBundleに保存しようとして、以下のように書き換えるとエラーになってしまいます。

```
var audioFilename: URL!

//Audio録音周りの関数
func startRecording() {
    audioFilename = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("recordedAudio.wav")

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()

    } catch {
        finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}

func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    audioRecorder = nil
}
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
CreateDataFile failed
Couldn't create a new audio file object
```

どうしたらDocumentフォルダではなくBundleにAudioファイルを保存することができますか？

Comment: Bundleというのは、アプリケーションが実行に必要なファイルをアプリ作成時にひとまとまりにするための仕組みであり、ビルド後(実行時)にその内容を書き換えることはできません。

Comment: ありがとうございます